# Angular2 bind http response to IFrame

Tags: angular, http, post, iframe

I have couple of questions on angular2.

1) how to fire the submit event on the form?
2) how to redirect/bind the http response to an IFrame?

I have an angular2 application which talks to external server and tries to load the response html along with its links (js, css). I have done this in aspx using the form post with a target to iframe. wondering how do i do the similar in Angular2?

```
<iframe #frame class="embed-responsive-item"
    width="100%" id="frame" name="frame" frameborder="0" 
    scrolling="no" ></iframe>

<form #form target="frame" (ngSubmit)="submitForm($event)"  >
 <input type="hidden" name="token" value={{token}}/>
 <button type="submit" >Submit the form</button>
</form>
```

Here's the sample plunker 
https://plnkr.co/edit/Z6yVvG1tBHAThCCTTpHi?p=preview

Comment: the cross-document messaging should be an answer to your question, you can read more about it at MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

I figured out action attribute with method does the trick here. I was able to call nativeelement.submit from nginit().

```
<form target="frame" action="http://www.website.com/postdata/" #form method="POST" hidden="hidden">
<input name="token" value={{token}}> 
</form>
```